# Is there any benefit in getting a `Tag Badges`?

Tags: discussion

Is there any benefit in getting a `Tag Badges`?

Or is simply to motivate the user to win it?

Comment: With a gold tag badge, you get the ability to single-handedly close as dupes questions with that tag.

Comment: This is a good question because I was surprised the first time this happened to me: voted to close a question with a tag I had a gold badge for, and it was suddenly closed, as @J.M. described. Then it dawned on me I have special powers now... So the previous comment may as well be added as an answer to draw attention to this feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote the documentation in [Help Center > Badges > Tags](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/133/) (which I didn't really read carefully myself, initially):

> Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the <kbd>plotting</kbd> tag. These users can single-handedly mark <kbd>plotting</kbd> questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed.

Comment: This actually makes me a lot more hesitant to mark a dupe, since no one else will be voting on it.

Comment: @user, Uncle Ben said something along the lines of "with great power comes..." y'know the rest.

Comment: Can we edit those movies together to use the first Uncle Ben and the second Peter Parker?

Comment: @user9490 [This is the movie I found.](http://giphy.com/gifs/spider-man-superhero-wee-zMDQIudRLFKco) Thanks a lot, internet.